# Python Memcached, connect to Azure VM server

Tags: memcached, azure-virtual-machine, python-memcached

I have installed Memcached on an Azure VM server (Ubuntu). I now need to connect to this from my Python program that runs elsewhere.

When they were installed on the same server, this worked:

```
import memcache
MEMCACHE_SOCKET_PATH = 'unix:<path_to>/memcached.sock'  
memcache_client = memcache.Client([MEMCACHE_SOCKET_PATH], debug=0)
```

Now I'm not sure what to use for MEMCACHE_SOCKET_PATH. The VM running Memcached has a static IP address and I have created an endpoint (opened a port) to 11211. memcached.sock sits in the home directory.

This is how I am running Memcached on the VM:

```
memcached -d -m 500 -s $HOME/memcached.sock -P $HOME/memcached.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description about the command to run memcached on Azure VM, I see your memcached was running with Unix domain socket, not TCP/IP. [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) is a IPC ([Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication))solution of data communications for exchanging data between processes executing on the same host operating system, it can not be used in a RPC ([Remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)) scenario.

So to fix it, you just need to start up memcached using `memcached.conf` and make it working on TCP/IP. If you were using the command `sudo apt-get install memcached` to install memcached, the `memcached.conf` file should be at the path `/etc/memcached.conf`. Then you can change it by using `sudo vim /etc/memcached.cond` to set the values of port `-p` & listen ip `-l`, as below.

```
-p 11211
-l 0.0.0.0
```

When you have added an inbound rule of your VM NSG network interface at the tab `Networking`, then you could connect the memcached service in Python via the tcp address `<your vm host ip>:<port like 11211>`.